# Is father-in-law to be correct?

Tags: american-english, spoken-english

Bride-to-be and groom-to-be are pretty much commonly used. My question is can we say father-in-law to be or mother-in-law to be? Or if that's not correct,  what do we say here?

Comment: If it were correct, it would need all the dashes (so, father-in-law-to-be) but I don't like it. I'd just say "future father-in-law".

Comment: Did you search for such usages? What did you find? That might answer your question. As a strict language question, of course you can. Another option would be "*future* father-in-law".

Comment: I found nothing on the internet.  It simply doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

You can say this, but there are better alternatives. It would need all the hyphens (so, "father-in-law-to-be") but I don't like it. I'd just say "future father-in-law".

If you jilt the bride-to-be or groom-to-be at the altar you can even say ex-father-in-law-to-be(!)

Comment: This answer was rather more like a comment than a question. On the other hand there were answers written as comments. Rather than make a new answer to this old question I've edited the comments into the answer.